# Configurable products ranking in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to generate a "best selling products" list on my magento site. I tried following the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288503/how-to-show-latest-top-rated-and-best-products-in-left-bar-in-magento). This works okay, however, I realized that this is only ideal for simple products. I am trying to create the ranking for configurable products so I believe I need to get the total orders for the simple products first which I'm not sure how I can do programmatically. This is basically the idea I have in mind:

> Get the simple products associated to a configurable product
>
> Get the total orders for each simple product and sum them up
>
> Pass the total sum to configurable products again (i'm thinking of using an array here) then call the necessary data ordered by ranking.

So far I have come up with this code:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');
foreach($_collection as $c):
$configurable = $c->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
foreach($configurable as $_config):
    $_simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_config);
                echo $_simple->getName()."<br/>";
                echo "qty:".(int)$_simple->ordered_qty."<br/>";
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
```

However, while trying to test it, all of my quantities return 0 so I'm stuck. How do I implement the ranking for configurable products? Please advise. Also, if possible, I'd like to make as little changes to the core files as possible.

Also, I have this ranking list limited to 10 and if the other products have 0 quantity sold, then they will automatically be sorted alphabetically. Same goes if for example 2 products have the same amount sold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After literally more than 8 hours of trying to figure this out. I've come up with some sort of workaround (at least it seems to work for my case), the code surely need a lot of improvement so I'd be glad to accept any modifications and suggestions to my answer. Here's the code I came up with:

```
$filler = array();

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
            ->setPage(1, 10);

foreach($productCollection as $product):
    echo "name:".$product->getName()." - qty:".(int)$product->ordered_qty."<br/>";
    array_push($filler, $product->getId());
endforeach;

if(count($productCollection) < 10):
    $add = 10 - count($productCollection);

    $fillCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
            ->setOrder('name', 'desc');

    foreach($fillCollection as $item): 
        if(in_array($item->getId(), $filler)):
        else:
            if($add > 0):
                echo "name:".$item->getName()." - qty: 0 <br/>";
                $add = $add - 1;
            endif;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;  
unset($filler);
```

So the basic idea of this is I get the collection for products with orders only since as it appears, products with 0 orders are not retrieved. After that, I get the number of items I still need to display 10 products on my ranking. Then, I get another collection of products and echo them as long as there's still less than 10 products displayed. I used the filler array to make sure that products already called by the first collection are not displayed. Given this code, I now have a ranking of best selling products in my magento site.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

I found that configurable product sales are being summed correctly but aren't being included in the results; their child products appear instead.  My solution was to include configurable products, do a left join on the `catalog_product_super_link` table, and filter out anything that has a `parent_id`.  Here are the changes you'll need to make:

Collection.php:

```
    public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '', $getComplexProducts=false, $getComplexChildProducts = true, $getRemovedProducts = true)
    {
        $qtyOrderedTableName = $this->getTable('sales/order_item');
        $qtyOrderedFieldName = 'qty_ordered';

        $productIdFieldName = 'product_id';

        if (!$getComplexProducts) {
            $compositeTypeIds = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getCompositeTypes();
            $productTypes = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(' AND (e.type_id NOT IN (?))', $compositeTypeIds);
        } else {
            $productTypes = '';
        }

        if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
            $dateFilter = " AND `order`.created_at BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}'";
        } else {
            $dateFilter = "";
        }

        $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
            array('order_items' => $qtyOrderedTableName),
            array(
                'ordered_qty' => "SUM(order_items.{$qtyOrderedFieldName})",
                'order_items_name' => 'order_items.name'
            )
        );

         $_joinCondition = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                'order.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND order.state<>?', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED
         );
         $_joinCondition .= $dateFilter;
         $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
            array('order' => $this->getTable('sales/order')),
            $_joinCondition,
            array()
         );

         // Add join to get the parent id for configurables
         $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
             array('cpsl' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_super_link')),
             'cpsl.product_id = order_items.product_id',
             'cpsl.parent_id'
         );

        if(!$getComplexChildProducts)
            $this->getSelect()->having('parent_id IS NULL');

        if($getRemovedProducts)
        {
             $this->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(array('e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()),
                    "e.entity_id = order_items.{$productIdFieldName} AND e.entity_type_id = {$this->getProductEntityTypeId()}{$productTypes}")
                ->group('order_items.product_id');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->getSelect()
                ->joinInner(array('e' => $this->getProductEntityTableName()),
                    "e.entity_id = order_items.{$productIdFieldName} AND e.entity_type_id = {$this->getProductEntityTypeId()}{$productTypes}")
                ->group('e.entity_id');
        }


        $this->getSelect()->having('ordered_qty > 0');

        // This line is for debug purposes, in case you'd like to see what the SQL looks like
        // $x = $this->getSelect()->__toString();

        return $this;
    }
```

List.php - Find the following two lines...

```
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty($startDate, $todayDate, true);
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty('', '', true);
```

... and change them to:

```
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty($startDate, $todayDate, true, false, false);
$bestsellers->addOrderedQty('', '', true, false, false);
```

My changes added two new optional parameters, which both default to `true`, as to not break existing functionality.

- When `$getComplexChildProducts` is set to `false`, all child items of the configurable product will be removed from the results.
- `$getRemovedProducts` determines whether or not previously ordered products (which have since been deleted from Magento) should also appear.

Please note that your report statistics will need to be up-to-date in order to get accurate results.

Source and acknowledgements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8419579/1136132