# Filtering product collection by 2 or more parameters in Magento

Tags: php, magento

In the process of trying to [create a best product ranking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630309/configurable-products-ranking-in-magento) for my Magento site, I came to another obstacle. I have 3 different stores with different products so I tried to add a store filter on my query so my query looks like this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
        ->setPage(1, 10);
```

The problem is, I noticed that if I add the addOrderedQty parameter, it completely ignores addStoreFilter so my ranking returns all products regardless of which store it's in. I tried to rearrange my query so I call ordered quantity before the store filter but with this, the query completely ignores the ordered quantity filter but it does get only the store specific products. Is it possible to make both parameters work together without ignoring either 1? Please help!

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069318/magento-addstorefilter-not-working

Comment: I'm kind of confused, what's the second parameter in of the joinfield?

Comment: ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product',? Do u mean 'catalog/category_product'. It's table name (eav)

Comment: Yeah, that one. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter("status", Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)     
            ->setPageSize(9)
            ->setCurPage(1) 
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->setOrder("ordered_qty", "desc")
            ->setStore($store)
            ->addStoreFilter($store);
```

hope this wil sure help you.

Comment: what is the issue ? is your are getting your store id ?

Comment: I am trying to get the product collection with store filter and ordered quantity filter. I tried this and it broke my site, I tried changing $store to $storeId instead and I ended up with alphabetically filtered items.

Comment: you splved ur problem

Comment: well, I'd like to filter it by ordered quantity for products in specific stores so I don't think my problem's fixed just yet.

Comment: http://www.magento.cc/how-to-sortshow-products-by-sold-quantity-in-magento.html pls check